# Trying to assign value to global object/Session object. Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, service, angular-components, session-storage

I created a service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SessionService implements ISession {
    private _session: string = "SomeValue";

constructor() {

}

set session(value) {
    this._session = value;
}

get session() {
    return this._session
}

}


export interface ISession {
    session: Object
}
```

Then tried to assign a value to it

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { SessionService } from "../../services/session.service";
import { ISession } from "../../services/session.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'survey',
    templateUrl: './survey.component.html'
})
export class SurveyComponent {
    public surveys: Survey[];




constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string, private sessionService : SessionService) {
    sessionService.session("xxx");

    http.get(baseUrl + 'api/survey').subscribe(result => {
        this.surveys = result.json() as Survey[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

}

sessionService.session("xxx");

Gives me the error. Help ?

Comment: Use `sessionService.session = "xxx"`

Answer (score 0):

I was posting to a new link with A HREF which would then reload everything and therefore reinitialize the static variable. BAD!.  Must use angular routing